# Testlist vs Playlist in MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, mstest

In VS2010 we used to have a Testlist option to group test cases. And I can ran those easily through command-line using MSTest /testlist option. Now I'm using VS 2013 and we have option of Playlist to group test. But I don't see this playlist option in MSTest command-line.

Do we have any workaround? I have to run the tests from command line from a Jenkins job.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Test Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286595.aspx) to group your unit tests. You could then use either [vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) with the parameter `/TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=MyCategoryForJenkins"` or [MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) with the parameters `/testcontainer:MyTests.dll /category:"MyCategoryForJenkins"`.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I stumbled across it and felt that the answer was still relevant for Jenkins set-ups today.